# Python: SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD) = No such protocol

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to make game server emulator (with uses probably SSLv3 for communicating)

And I'm trying to make SSL socket with SSLv3 support

Here is the line with causes problem:`context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)`
Is resulting with this: `ValueError: No such protocol`

Additionally i tryed to use `SSL.SSLv23_METHOD` - works but while client is trying to connect i'm getting this error:

`OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_client_hello', 'version too low')]`

As you can see I'm getting the 'version too low' error, that's why I'm trying to make the SSLv3 server.

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

SSLv3 is considered insecure and should no longer be used. Because of this many current installation of OpenSSL come without support for SSLv3, i.e. it is not compiled into the library. In this case you get the error about unsupported method if you try to explicitly use it and you get a similar error if the SSL handshake fails because the peer tries to use this locally unsupported TLS version.

> Is there any way to fix that?

Don't try to enforce use of SSLv3. Instead use the sane and secure default protocol setting.